# Ruta no soportada en Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, rutas, eliminar

tengo un problema de lógica con las rutas que no logro solventar, estoy trabajando con laravel 8, tengo un proyecto donde el usuario debe visualizar la deuda de los clientes y luego mediante un botón "ver" uso el ID del usuario para visualizar los productos que a comprado en un lista con botones para editar y borrar.Pero cuando intento editar o borrar algo me arroja el error que dice solo soportar ruta de tipo "GET". Este es mi código.

```
    Router::get('/Deudas',[DeudaController::class, 'index']) ----> Lo uso para traer los montos  deudores de los clientes y mostrarlos en una tabla.

Router::get('/Deudas/detalles/{id}',[DeudaController::class, 'Detalles']) ----> Lo uso para traer los Artículos comprados por el cliente seleccionado.

Router::Delete('/Deudas/eliminar/{id}',[DeudaController::class, 'Eliminar']) ----> Lo uso para borrar un dato de los productos mostrados, pero no funciona, me arroja error 404 o no existe.

Cuando intento.

Router::Delete('/Deudas/detalles/eliminar/{id}',[DeudaController::class, 'Eliminar']) --->Sale el error  ruta GET no soportada, solo métodos "DELETE".
```

Soy nuevo en el framework, entiendo si no me doy a entender.

Comment: Es porque estás llamando a esa ruta como GET, en cambio debe ser por medio de un formulario POST, indicandole que utilice el método DELETE de tu controlador mediante un hidden input, <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">, o bien, cambia el metodo por Router::get en lugar de Delete

Comment: También ten en cuenta que no es `Router::Delete` sino `Router::delete` en minúsculas. Mira [Available Router Methods](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#available-router-methods). Y para lo que preguntas, típicamente se hace un form con el input que te mencionaron, te sugiero leer [Form Method Spoofing](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#form-method-spoofing)

Comment: Hola, ya logré resolverlo, estoy usando Ajax, no se estaban pasando la ruta que era, gracias